# Canvas.drawBitmap or Canvas.drawColor not working

Tags: android, android-canvas, surfaceview, android-bitmap

I need to draw bitmaps on Surfaceview at speed of 15 fps, my SurfaceView is as follows

```
public class RawVideoViewSV extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

private boolean isSurface;
private Bitmap mBitmap;
private SurfaceHolder holder;

public RawVideoViewSV(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
     holder = getHolder();
     holder.addCallback(this); 
}


@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    isSurface = false;
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    isSurface = true;
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    isSurface = false;
}

public SurfaceHolder getSurfaceHolder(){
    return holder;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(isSurface){
        canvas.drawColor(Color.GREEN);
        if(mBitmap != null)
            canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, null);
    }
}


public void doDraw(Canvas canvas,Bitmap bmp) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("RawVideoViewSV---> doDraw isSurface = " + isSurface + bmp.getHeight());
    Rect source = new Rect(0, 0, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight());
    if(isSurface){
        canvas.drawColor(Color.GREEN);
        if(bmp != null)
            canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, null,source, null);
    }
}}
```

In my activity am creating bitmaps which am passing it onto Surface to draw, but for some reason neither canvas.drawcolor is working nor canvas.drawbitmap is working inside the surfacview.

```
rawVideoViewSV0 = (RawVideoViewSV) findViewById(R.id.videoRawViewSV0);
Bitmap bmpx = Bitmap.createBitmap(rgb, videoSample.getWidth(),
videoSample.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas mCanvas = null;
    SurfaceHolder mHolder = rawVideoViewSV0.getHolder();

    try {
        mCanvas = mHolder.lockCanvas();
        synchronized (mHolder) {    
            rawVideoViewSV0.doDraw(mCanvas,bmpx);
        }
    } finally {                   
        if (mCanvas != null) {
            mHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(mCanvas);
        }
    }
```

rawVideoViewSV0 is of type RawVideoViewSV.
I have verified my bitmap is not null, only first time when onDraw gets called the surfaceview appears green that's it.

Please can someone point me where am going wrong.

Comment: you know that surfaceview set "will no draw" flag to true? ... whatever you are trying to achive here(watermark on video from cam/file?), you are doing it wrong ...

Comment: I have figured out where i was going wrong it has worked now... thanks for quick responses..

Answer (score 0):

A SurfaceView has two parts, the Surface and the View.  The View is drawn with the rest of the UI, but is generally just a transparent "hole" used for layout purposes.  The Surface appears on a separate layer below the UI.

It looks like you're writing video frames to the Surface, and then covering them up with a solid green View.  Remove the `onDraw()` function (which gets a Canvas for the View part) and do everything in `doDraw()` (which gets a Canvas for the Surface part).